# whether it's absolutely convergent

Tags: convergence-divergence

I want to know how to use a simple method to prove $\sum\frac{\sin(n)sin(n^2)}{n}$ is absolutely convergent?

Comment: Try to show your attempt.

Comment: I can only prove it's convergent

Comment: @lynor How? Show us.